# avoid access syscall with php apc

Tags: php, apc, system-calls, strace

I'm trying avoid any unneeded syscall for an apache+php website.

So far I made the following changes:

- `apc.stat = false` (to avoid apc checking file for updates)
- use `include` instead of `include_once` (to avoid getting realpath of file)
- use absolute paths instead of relative paths for `include`
- disabled xdebug extension

When testing [using strace](http://endlessgeek.com/2014/03/strace-php-process-via-apache/) I don't see any `stat` calls (the above changes removed them), but I still see `access` calls (one for every included file):

```
24592      0.000157 access("/var/www/testweb/vendor/vivid-planet/koala-framework/Kwf/Cache/Simple.php", F_OK) = 0
24592      0.000215 access("/var/www/testweb/vendor/zf1/zend-registry/library/Zend/Registry.php", F_OK) = 0
```

What causes them and how can I avoid those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the cause for the `access` syscall, it's a file_exists in the Composer `ClassLoader`.

To avoid that it seems I have to write my own loader...